# How can I trim a text array in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, trim

Is it possible to trim a text array in PostgreSQL? If so, how?

I want to get something like:

```
    select trim(myTextArrayColumn) from myTable;
```

where myTextArrayColumn is of type text[].

Example column values:

```
    {"someData1 ", "someData2 "}

    {" someData3 "}
```

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
select array_agg(trim(e))
from (
  select row_number() over () as rn, 
         unnest(myTextArrayColumn) e
  from mytable
) t
group by rn
```

Comment: Works smoothly! (I'm using postgres 13.x)

Answer (score 2):

try this, i think suitable for your

```
select string_to_array(replace(array_to_string(arrColumn, '::'), ' ', ''), '::') from myTable
```

**note**: 1. all spaces will be removed 2. your values must does not contains '::', if contains use other delimeter

Comment: To avoid replacing all spaces, you can trim with this modification,

`select string_to_array(replace(replace(array_to_string(arrColumn, '::'), ' ::', '::'), ':: ', '::'), '::') from myTable`