# How to remove white space on array elements

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I have a column called 'rest_type' which is data type text[]. inside it are ["Fine Dining", " Cafe", " Bar"] etc. how can i remove the whitespaces in these elements?

```
   rest_type
-------------------------------
 {"Quick Bites"}
 {Cafe}
 {Cafe}
 {"Quick Bites"}
 {"Sweet Shop"," Quick Bites"}
```

(5 rows)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I trim a text array in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11700930/how-can-i-trim-a-text-array-in-postgresql)

Comment: You should be more specific about what whitespace you want remove, leading/trailing or all? For example `" Quick Bites"` to `"Quick Bites"` or `"QuickBites"`